Any potential problem in linking to the dynamic libraries compiled by lower version compiler?
Is there any potential problem under such condition?
My project use g++11.4 to compile while the needed dynamic libraries out of my control are compiled with g++ 8.2.

Yes, this definitely has potential problems. The actual code is the least of your problems; your CPU is obviously one that was supported back in GCC 8.2 and still supported in G++11.4. And for those CPU's, the calling conventions are unchanged.
What is a potential problem is glibc, and particularly its rather weak versioning. You can't target a specific version, your linker will pick whatever the OS (!) was using at the time. And their linker picked whatever their OS was using at the time.
There's also the minor matter of _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI - stdlibc++ changed the ABI of std::string around GCC5, and allowed you to choose between C++11 and backwards compatibility. You have to check if you use the same setting as those libraries did.

Thank you for the rapid reply. 1. "your CPU is obviously one that was supported back in GCC 8.2 and still supported in G++11.4. And for those CPU's, the calling conventions are unchanged."  You mean G++8.2 and G++11.4 generate the assembly code uisng the same CPU instruction set? Am I right? 2. You said that "There's also the minor matter of _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI - stdlibc++ changed the ABI of std::string around GCC5".  How to know whether _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI is compatible or not?

@John: No, I meant calling convention. MSVC on Windows also uses the same CPU instruction set, but for a call you need to agree on more details. E.g. where do you store the arguments for a function call ? How is the stack laid out?
